# how to get the num with pnum and the highest price of order from the given set in sql, only the highest value per num

Tags: sql

```
 num     Pnum    price
-------- ---   -------
     1   109       30
     1   118       25
     3   101       30
     3   115       27
     4   107       23
     5   100       17
     5   129       16
```

ans should be:

```
 num     Pnum    price
-------- ---   -------
     1   109       30
     3   101       30
     4   107       23
     5   100       17
```

Comment: You really need to have a go at this yourself and then post questions for any specific problems you're having.

Comment: @Oberoi Try to include what you have tried when you post your questions. I have written an answer to your problem. Check it out below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have assumed the table name as `Numbers`

```
SELECT N2.* from 
(SELECT num, max(price) AS price FROM Numbers
GROUP BY num) AS N1
INNER JOIN Numbers N2 on N2.num=N1.num and N2.price = N1.price
```

[DB Fiddle Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ucGLtH2e1i7wrvGrAZf5H6/0)